# Table elements doesn't respond to edit no matter what I do

Tags: html, css

I want to make a table for foods and nutrition,but there is a problem.No matter what i do width of the`<td>` and `<th>` elements won't change...I want my table to look something like [this](http://prntscr.com/djo52x) (without the header) Instead of [THIS](http://prntscr.com/djo5lf)

```css
#table1{
  table-layout:fixed;
  width:100%;
}
.row1 > th{
  border-right:1px solid #ddd;
  padding:0.75em;
}
```

```html
<table id="table1">
  <thead>
    <tr class="row1">
      <th>Foods</th><th>Carbohydrates</th><th>Proteins</th><th>Fats</th><th>Calories Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="row2">
      <th>Foods</th><th>Carbohydrates</th><th>Proteins</th><th>Fats</th><th>Calories Total</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Because `.Table1-row1` doesn't exists. You probably meant `#table1 .row1 th{ /* your th styles */ }`. Also, `th` elements should be only in the `thead`.

Comment: Sorry,my bad i edited the snippet.It was just a snippet mistake,i was changing  my classes when i was pasting the snippet and i forgot to change it in here.

Comment: If you look at your snipper you'll see that it's working - it's adding styles to the `th` elements in the `.row1`.

Comment: Also replaced <th> element which are out of the <thead> with <td> and it become better,but still not the result i wanted.

Comment: I know it is working,but i cannot make first TH element larger.Heres one more example http://prntscr.com/djoc60

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ther's no `.Table1` class in your html. Simply use `.row1 > th`

To set width of `th` you can use:

```
th:nth-child(1) {
    width: 15%;
}
```

```css
#table1{
table-layout:fixed;
width:100%;
}
.row1 > th{
border-right:1px solid #ddd;
padding:0.75em;
}
.row2 > th{
border-right:1px solid #ddd;
padding:0.75em;
}
th:nth-child(1) {
    width: 10%;
}
th:nth-child(2) {
    width: 35%;
}
th:nth-child(3) {
    width: 15%;
}
th:nth-child(4) {
    width: 15%;
}
th:nth-child(5) {
    width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<table id="table1">
<thead>
<tr class="row1">
<th>Foods</th><th>Carbohydrates</th><th>Proteins</th><th>Fats</th><th>Calories Total</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="row2"><th>Foods</th><th>Carbohydrates</th><th>Proteins</th><th>Fats</th><th>Calories Total</th></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the time mate, it was my mistake i didn't replace the classes  in the snippet.Because when i was adding classes here i was renaming them in my site and messed up.I tried your suggestion with :nth-child(1) it works,but pulling my whole row when i resize this cell,is there a way to resize it without it pulling all of content:?

Comment: What do you mean by "pulling whole row"?

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you are looking for?

```css
#table1{
  table-layout:fixed;
  width:100%;
}
.row1 > th, .row2 > td{
  border-right:1px solid #ddd;
  padding:0.75em;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<table id="table1">
  <thead>
    <tr class="row1">
      <th style="width:40%;">Foods</th>
      <th style="width:20%;">Carbohydrates</th>
      <th style="width:15%;">Proteins</th>
      <th style="width:10%;">Fats</th>
      <th style="width:15%;">Calories Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="row2">
      <td>Foods</td>
      <td>Carbohydrates</td>
      <td>Proteins</td>
      <td>Fats</td>
      <td>Calories Total</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```